# Koala gem get_picture with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, koala, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I want retrieve JSON with information about user picture. With simple:

```
@graph.get_picture('some_user_id')
```

I got only link to picture. And I want get JSON with some data ([like described here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/picture#readfields)). But when I do next:

```
@graph.get_picture('some_user_id', {redirect: false})
```

I always get nil instead of JSON.

Moreover, this construction:

```
@graph.get_picture('some_user_id', {type: 'large'})
```

works fine. I get my large image. But with `redirect` argument something wrong.

Comment: what is the response of `@graph.get_picture('some_user_id')` ? Does it return picture id that is object id in the response ?

Comment: It returns only link to picture.